# Miss aligned state loading/storing gas costs

Tags: storage, gas-price

For a smart contract idea that spins around in my head, I have the situation where I have to conserve the old values of a variable (no storage refund or cheaper `SSTORE` updates). As the value I write is comparatively big I wanted to estimate the gas cost that will occur and I realized that it would be cheaper to each time create a new contract with the data as code and then read it over `EXTCODECOPY` instead of using `SSTORE` and `SLOAD`.

A `CREATE` costs according to the yellow paper 32000 + 6400 per word (200 per byte), whereas an `SSTORE` costs 20000 per Word. in the `CREATE` case another 20000 are needed to store the address, so already with 4+ words stored the contract creation is cheaper.

An `EXTCODECOPY` costs 700 + 3 per Word (+200 to load the address with `LOAD`), whereas the `SLOAD` costs 200 per word. Here we need 5+ words for the contract creation to be cheaper.

I'm interested in the reason behind this, why is the intended way more expensive than a way where we misuse the `CREATE` opcode. Is one of the two ways underpriced or overpriced?

Even if in cases where the updating `SSTORE` (cost 5000 instead of 20000) is used it would still be beneficial in the cases where we update rarely in comparison to the expected reads.